# Java, JFrame not rendering components after adding a JTextfield

Tags: rendering, jtextfield

So I installed Eclipse on my laptop, and started a new school project. My program runs fine until I add a JTextfield, when I do that it will only show a empty grey JFrame instead of the JFrame with all my components in it. If I remove the line of code with the JTextfield it is all shown again when I run. Also with the JTextfield line the JFrame is grey, until I resize the window, then everything is shown fine.. but I dont wanna have to resize my JFrame every time I run it..
First I was running Java 7, so downgraded to Java 6 but am still having the same problem...

so adding this:

```
JTextField txtMyField = new JTextField(10);
myFrame.add(txtMyField);
```

will mess things up, and removing these 2 lines of code will make it work again..
I have tried making a new project, it works fine until I add a textfield.
I tried a new workspace in eclipse, works fine until I add a textfield..

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, make the jframe visible `myjframe.setVisible(true);` after adding all the swing components.

Answer (score 0):

Without your exact code i can only assume however.

if you call myFrame.add(txtMyField); you are adding it at the same level as the JPanel. try this

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
panel.add(field1)

JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
panel.add(field2);

add(panel);
```

this will add 2 textfield to a panel and the panel to the frame.. the panel by default as a FlowLayout which will float them together see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to other layouts.

Comment: No that isn't the problem. I am adding the textfield to a jpanel that i put on the jframe. But the problem is not my code, the problem is something with a Java rendering mistake or a graphics issue or something like that..